# Import a directory in QML

Tags: windows, qml, qt5

I’ve been reading documentation to import directories in QML: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html and I am not sure how to import from a different drive.

I have a QML file that imports an absolute path to another drive:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "D:/My Documents/SametimeFileTransfers/importsTest/Level3/"

Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {

        }
    }

    Cuadro{
        id: yo
        color:"red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                yo.color="yellow";
                yo.cambia("hola");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*If I try to load this QML file I get an error.*

According to the documentation, importing an absolute path is available but I am not sure how to do that.

I have the file “main.qml” located somewhere in drive C: and I would like to import a QML directory located in drive D:

If this is possible, How can I import the contents of a directory in a different drive?

Any comment regarding this issue is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

`import "file:///D:/My Documents/SametimeFileTransfers/importsTest/Level3/" as MyControls`

You can access your control as

`MyControls.Cuadro`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
I tried to import the directory and place an identifier or local namespace, as you explained, but it’s also not working.

Comment: Works for me. Qt creator doesn't recognize my custom control in the directory but the control gets displayed when run.

Comment: Oh OK, I missed the "file:///" part when I tried your approach. Now my path gets imported even if I don't use a namespace. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Can you please share your full example ? Did you do any import in .pro file also?

Comment: This is a super non-portable way of doing things